# Type mismatch Browser error when trying to pass browser and page title to function - UFT

Tags: vbscript, qtp

If I use the same code in my driver script it works fine, however, when I call it using a function, it throws an error saying, type mismatch Browser

function call: `validateTextonPage "Edit delivery","Edit delivery", "delivery#"`

```
Function validateTextonPage (browser, page, comptext)

    'print browser
    'print page

    mytext = Browser("title:=" & browser).Page("title:=" & page).GetROProperty("innertext")
    'print mytext

    strmatch = Instr(1, mytext, comptext)

    if strmatch <> 0 then
        Msgbox "Text found"
    else
        Msgbox "Not found"

    End If
End Function
```

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to give types to your function parameters.  Option Strict is your friend.

Comment: This looks like VBScript, not VB.net, based on MsgBox call without parentheses.

Comment: You are passing a script in the `browser` parameter. How you expect `Browser("title:=" & browser)` to work is `Browser` is a string?

Comment: Yes browser and page both are strings

Answer (score 1):

Vbscript is case inSeNsiTiVE, this means that your `browser` parameter overrides the `Browser` test object type. Try renaming `browser` and `page` to `browserTitle` and `pageTitle`.